# Spark JDBC write to Salesforce error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, salesforce

I am trying to read data from Hive and Writing to a custom object in Salesforce using a JDBC drive for Salesforce from Progress. Here is how I am trying to do this

```
spark-shell --jars /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/sforce.jar
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive._
val hc = new HiveContext(sc)
val results = hc.sql("select rep_name FROM schema.rpt_view")
print(results.first())
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
val url="jdbc:datadirect:sforce://login.salesforce.com"
val prop = new java.util.Properties
prop.put("user","user1")
prop.put("password","passwd")
prop.put("driver","com.ddtek.jdbc.sforce.SForceDriver")
results.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(url,"SFORCE.test_tab1",prop)`
```

I am getting the error

```
 `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: [DataDirect][SForce JDBC Driver][SForce]column size is required in statement [CREATE TABLE SFORCE.test_tab1 (rep_name TEXT`
```

Can some help me here .. if table test_tab1 already exists , how do I configure the write and also if table doesn't exist in Salesforce, how do I add a column value